# How to stop the Windows login when user isn't in my custom table MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication, custom-error-pages

I've got in intranet application that takes windows Authentication and a custom Users table in my db that allows access. My issue is if a user doesn't exist in my custom table, the system asks for their credentials instead of redirecting to my error page. If the user clicks cancel or tries 3 times, they end up on a generic 401 page.

What am I missing to get them to a friendly page for better direction?

UPDATE: 
I've also added my custom error page to IIS with no change in result

My global.asax

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(e.Identity);
                IUserRepository dUser = new UserRepository(new DARDbEntities());
                var userName = identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
                User user = dUser.Get(userName);
                if(user == null)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                }
```

My Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPage/NotFound" />
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/ErrorPage/NotAuthorized"/>
    </customErrors>
```

and my ErrorController:

```
namespace DailyAdmin.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class ErrorPageController : Controller
    {
        // GET: ErrorPage
        public ActionResult Error(int statusCode, Exception exception)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
            ViewBag.StatusCode = statusCode + " Error";
            ViewBag.errMessage = exception.Message;
            //var vm = new BaseViewModel{
            //    PageTitle = statusCode + " Error",
            //    ErrorMessage = exception.Message
            //};
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult NotAuthorized()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After the user clicks or tries three times...just redirect them to the page you want.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani, you are absolutely right. I was trying to hard and overthinking the problem, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was a simple redirect.

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(e.Identity);
                IUserRepository dUser = new UserRepository(new DARDbEntities());
                var userName = identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
                User user = dUser.Get(userName);
                if(user == null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("401.html");
                }
```

I was being too cute with the custom errors stuff.